# Using cells as output table of while loop in octave

Tags: loops, while-loop, octave

So I'm implementing a while loop in my code that just does some simple calculations. The thing is, that I want to have an output that no only shows the final values but all of them from each step. The best I could do was using cell arrays with the following code:

```
i=1; p=(a+b)/2;
valores=cell(n, 3);
while (i<=n && f(p)!=0);
  if f(a)*f(p)<0;
    a=a; b=p;
    else a=p; b=b;
  endif
  i=i+1; p=(a+b)/2;
  valores(i, :)={i-1 p f(p)}; fprintf('%d     %d      %d \n', valores{i, :});
endwhile
```

An example output would be:

```
1     1.25      -1.40998
2     1.125      -0.60908
3     1.0625      -0.266982
4     1.03125      -0.111148
5     1.01562      -0.0370029
```

But I have two main issues with this method, the first one is that I couldn't find a way to get some text as title in the first line, so I have to explain what each column in a sentence later, and second I don't know how to make it so that all the columns stay at the same distance from each other instead of each text staying at the same distance. I assume this last issue has something to do with the way I used the fprintf line since I'm not to familiar with it.

In case it helps to understand what I want to get from this algorithm, I'm trying to calculate the root of a function with the bisection method. And sorry if this was to long or unclear, feel free to give me advise, I'm kinda new here :)

Comment: Read the documentation on how to format your numbers with a fixed number of digits: https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Output-Conversion-Syntax.html#Output-Conversion-Syntax

Comment: To get a first line with names for each column, use another `fprintf` statement before your loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how to close the question or check your answer so I write this, although I know shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open-source package called [Tablicious](https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious) can take care of cell, row, and column alignment.  Using print statements and whitespace gets tedious and leads to unmaintainable code.

> Tablicious is a package for GNU Octave that provides relational data structures for Octave. It includes implementations of table arrays, datetime, string, categorical, and some other related stuff. You can think of it as “pandas for Octave”.

**Installation**

```
pkg install https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious/releases/download/v0.3.6/tablicious-0.3.6.tar.gz
```

**Example**

```
pkg load tablicious

Forename = {"Tom"; "Dick"; "Harry"};
Age = [21; 63; 38];
Salary = {"$1"; "$2"; "$3"};

tab = table(Forename, Age, Salary);
prettyprint (tab)
```

**Result**

```
-------------------------------
| Forename  | Age |   Salary  |
-------------------------------
| Tom       | 21   | $1       |
| Dick      | 63   | $2       |
| Harry     | 38   | $3       |
-------------------------------
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://tablicious.janklab.net/).